# Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7

Tags: hibernate, dmesg, systemd-logind

Few days back, I ran `dmesg` on my terminal to see this line `Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7`

Sometimes, as in the image below, the kernel ring buffer only prints this line repeatedly!

[image: diagnostic message]

What is this diagnostic message regarding, and what does it mean? What should I be doing if it is something that I should be dealing with immediately?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Linux with UEFI with secure boot requires a signed encrypted swap - which currently is not supported in Linux!

The bigger question is why does systemd-logind trigger this?  It isn't trying to hibernate.

On my machine, this is particularly irksome since it leaves my keyboard unresponsive for up to 30 seconds when I first boot or resume from sleep (Kubuntu 20.10).

Comment: @s-y-lerner Did you find a solution or woarkaround to the symptoms you described?

Comment: Since the encrypted swap/hibernation partition needs to be signed, I'm out of luck since this isn't currently supported.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, the referred manual: [`man kernel_lockdown.7`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man7/kernel_lockdown.7.html):

> Certain facilities are restricted:
> · Unencrypted hibernation/suspend to swap are disallowed...

That pretty much sums it up: enabling swap encryption should fix the problem.

Comment: This is not actually the full story: Having swap on e.g. encrypted LUKS still allows root to modify the swap partition, which is what this protection is guarding against. The swap actually has to be *signed*, not *encrypted*, and this is not currently supported by Linux AFAIU (so the manpage is a bit misleading there). See also https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/58077.html for more background.